# Converting my Linked List to doubly Linked List, but having issues with accessing previous at insertHead

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I get an error error trying to access "previous" in something not a structure or union on this line of code:
*head->previous = newHead

I'm not quite sure why... Any help is much appreciated.

```
`
struct ListNode
{
     int value;
     struct ListNode* next;
     struct ListNode* previous;
};

void insertAtHead(struct ListNode** head,int val)
{
     struct ListNode* newHead = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
     newHead->value = val;
     newHead->next = NULL;
     newHead->previous = NULL;
     if(*head == NULL)
         *head = newHead;
     else
     {
         newHead->next = *head;
         *head->previous = newHead;
         *head = newHead;
     } 
}`
```

Comment: Try `(*head)->previous`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `->` operator has [higher precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) than `*`. So,
 `*head->previous` is grouped as `*(head->previous)`, which is not what you want. Use parenthesis:

```
(*head)->previous = newHead;
```